# Cross GUI Thread Drag Drop operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have an application which is currently three forms. Two of the forms have grid controls which are running on separate GUI threads. I understand that running separate gui threads is not the norm but performance requirements are forcing me to adopt this path. The third form has a set of items in a ListView Box that can be dragged and dropped on the other two forms.The problem I'm having is implementing this drag/drop functionality. I initially had this application running on a single gui thread and drag/drop worked fine then. Since separating them out, I'm having issues with cross thread operation. Here is sample of my code.

```
private void grid1_DragDropContent(object sender, DragDropContentEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Content == null)
    {

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;

       ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items =                                  e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)) as
                            ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection;
         // Code Breaks Here
         foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
         {
             ......
         }

    }
  }
}
```

I get an exception when trying to access each of the ListViewItems since they were created on a different thread. I know cross thread operations are usually resolved by using Invoke , but I'm unsure on how to use it here since the SelectedListViewItemCollection does not give me access to the underlying ListView. Is there anyway to resolve this issue ? All help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are doing a lot of stuff on the GUI thread which you should not be doing there, I really cannot see how one would need multiple GUI threads. I think you are now trying to fix problems you are running into because you came up with the wrong solution to your performance problem. Any operation that is not direct GUI logic should be done in a separate worker thread. Do that, go back to having just one GUI thread, and the problem is gone.

Comment: The reason I'm forced to have two gui threads is that the grid gets tremendous amount of updates every second. So whats happening is one grid is constantly redrawing while the other is still waiting for its paint message. The other grid doesn't redraw until it is activated or moved at which point the first grid stops updating. It seems like  given the number of udpates we are processing, only one grid is capable is keeping up with the re draws hence the multiple gui threads.

Comment: If you are getting updates that fast, do you have to redraw every time?  Can you try to inject some code that buffers the updates to the grid, so that it only refreshes every half second, or tenth second? (I know that's not the solution you are asking for, but it seems like the real problem here is managing grid redraws, and that anything else seems more like treating the symptoms than the problem -- just my 2 cents)

Comment: If the grid is constantly redrawing, it is never really usable. I would agree with @JMarsch, the solution is to buffer updates and only refresh periodically. Multiple GUI threads just *isn't* the solution, as it is causing you more problems than it benefits you.